# OnSessionChange does not work sometimes

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-services

I have a windows service that should check log in and log out of all users and insert them all in a table.I have used *OnSessionChange()* and *OnShutDown()* events in my service to do that.It sometimes works fine but sometimes nothing happen when a user logging in or shutting down without any error,i think sometimes those events do not fire.

I do not know what is my mistake??

**EDIT :**

I want to create a winservice to save log in and log out time of all accounts in a domain.
I have tried OnSessionChange() and check out the SessionChangeDescription property but it sometimes does not work correctly, so i decided to use api functions to do that.
In order to my searches LsaGetLogonSessionData and maybe ISensLogon2 functions can return what i want. but the question is that where should i use this function? Should i call this function in an event or it can diagnose the log ins and log outs itself?

I'm waiting yet for your replies....
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your service wasn't started before the fired event when logging in.
But Log-out should works for those reason.

You should check first that "CanHandleSessionChangeEvent" and "CanHandlePowerEvent" are True.

Answer (score 0):

for those who has problem with fetch username from SessionChangeDescription.SessionId:

sometimes, in SessionLogoff when you need access user that logged off,log off action did fast and SessionId lost.

my solution was this:

1.define a global array(like `Dictionary<int, string> userlist`)

2.store session id and usernames in SessionLogon event(like `userlist.Add(SessionChangeDescription.SessionId,GetUsernameBySessionId(SessionChangeDescription.SessionId)`)

3.access username in every where by array(like `userlist[changeDescription.SessionId]`)